# Java calculator add numbers to textfield

Tags: java, button, textfield, calculator

I am making a calculator to test my skills in java. How can make the numbers to show up in the jTextfield until i pressed  one button to calculate the numbers;   i want every numbers to show up in the textfield.  for example if i pressed 1 and zero i want the textfield to have 10.

```
int num;
JTextField in = new JTextField(20); // input field where numbers will up;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == bouttons.get(0)) {
        num = 0;
        in.setText("" + num);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == bouttons.get(1)) {
        int num = 1;
        in.setText("" + num);
    }
}
```

[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVm8J.png)

Comment: can you share the complete code. it seems you are not appending the text

Comment: See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556) for tips.

Answer (score 2):

To save yourself the hassle of a lot of `if-else` you can create an array of `JButton`s and go over them in a loop.
So button 0 will be at index 0.

Then, you can append the text to the `JTextField` as:

```
String alreadyDisplayed = in.getText(); //get the existing text
String toDisplay = alreadyDisplayed + Integer.toString(loopCounter);// append the position to the text
in.setText(toDisplay);// display the text
```

You can loop as follows:

```
for(int i=0;i<jbuttonArray.length;i++){
    if(e.getSource()==jbuttonArray[i]){
        //insert above code here;
    }
}
```

Here is the tutorial by Oracle on this subject: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html

Answer (score 2):

You want to append the text to whatever already is there - try something like

`in.setText(in.getText() + num)` instead of `in.setText("" + num)`

Answer (score 1):

you should append with `in.getText()` instead of empty String

```
int num ;
JTextField in = new JTextField(20); // input field where numbers will up;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



    if (e.getSource() == bouttons.get(0)) {

        num =0;

        in.setText(in.getText() + num);

    }

    if (e.getSource() == bouttons.get(1)) {

        int num = 1;
        in.setText(in.getText() + num);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `ActionListener` to the numeric button. For eg: if you have a `JButton b1` that add `1` to the *textfield*... You could use it like this:

```java
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        /* I'm using equals method because I feel that it is more reliable than '==' operator
         * but you can also use '=='
         */
        if(e.getSource().equals(b1){
            in.setText(in.getText + "1");
        }
    }
```

And similarly you could add other buttons for `1,2,3`... and *implement* it like this.

*Hope this will help you.... :-) :-)*